# Conditional Flags Assembly - cmp, test

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm having a hard time understanding conditional code in assembly. The assembly on the right is for funA() on the left, but I'm having trouble with lines 3-4 in assembly.

Here is my thought process:

```
cmp rax, rcx // a[idx] <= *b
```

However, the actual if statement in the code is the exact opposite. I know it has something to do with how in assembly, the conditional executed is the reverse...therefore it makes a[idx] > *b instead. 
Does this have to do with "jle"? Would someone mind explaining this to me?

[image][image]

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Comment: He just wanted to catch the attention of Jon Skeet :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at .L1 and .L2, the JIT compiler has just decided to reverse the order - it's put the `else` code first, and reversed the condition. The `jle` is "jump if less than or equal" so it's become the equivalent of the C#:

```
if (a[idx] <= *b)
{
    *b = *b + *b;
}
else
{
    *b = a[idx];
}
```

Comment: thank you! that makes a lot more sense when it's written out like that. I'll make sure to do that next time so I don't confuse myself.